# Output file of a batch remains locked when launched with Win32_Process

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I'm using this VBScript to launch a command file in a hidden window: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/8bbed56f-a7aa-491f-a296-687dd96098a3

Also, I'm redirecting the outputs of the cmd to a file, for logging purpose.

My VBScript is basically:

```
Const HIDDEN_WINDOW = 12

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.ShowWindow = HIDDEN_WINDOW
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")

errReturn = objProcess.Create("C:\Temp\test.cmd > C:\Temp\log.txt", null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

The command file installs a program then launches it. For the example, let's say it just displays a message then launches notepad:

```
echo whatever

start "" notepad.exe
```

When launching the VBScript (either with wscript or by double-clicking on it), the command file is executed in a hidden window, the output is stored in log.txt, and notepad is started. As expected.

The problem is that the log.txt file remains locked until notepad is closed (impossible to delete or modify it). The command file shouldn't wait for the notepad process to exit since I'm using the `start` command. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

**Edit:**

Thanks to Bali C, a much shorter version of the script:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\Temp\test.cmd > C:\Temp\log.txt"), 0, True
```

However, the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your script doesn't work, but this is much shorter and works for me

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\Temp\test.cmd >C:\Temp\log.txt"), 0, True
```

Comment: This is much shorter, but `log.txt` is still locked until notepad closes.

Comment: Indeed, it's so much shorter that the other script feels a bit ridiculous. But as @aphoria mentioned, the log file is locked (impossible to modify or delete) until notepad is closed. Tested on Windows XP and Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Very strange, but I can't find any way around it, sorry!

Comment: I can't delete it until notepad closes. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Yeah I am too, I think I had closed notepad by accident when I did it, I tried it again and got the it's in use error.

Comment: You can add a taskkill /f /im notepad.exe line in your code to close notepad, though depending on the intended user, this may have intended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only option is to redirect each line of the batch, except for the line that starts notepad.

```
ECHO whatever>>log.txt

START "" notepad.exe

ECHO blah blah blah>>log.txt
```